# Turn four rows into running page header in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, formatting, office365

I have an Excel sheet that I'm trying to format for print. I want to turn the top four rows of the sheet (or quite frankly any four rows, I don't care where they're stored) into the header so that they will appear on the top of every sheet.

In terms of creating a header, Excel seems fairly limited. Is there any method I can use to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Page Layout, Page Setup, Sheet, then select the rows you want to repeat at the top of every page in the "Rows to repeat at top" box:

[image]